# Mounted network drive: cwd can't find current directory

Tags: mount, directory

I'm on Debian using python3.7. I have a network drive that I typically mount to /media/N_drive with dir_mode=0777 and file_mode=0777. I generally have no issues with reading/writing files in this network drive.

However, occasionally if I run a Python script while in the mounted network drive, the `os.getcwd()` command fails, giving a `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory` error. If I do `os.chdir` to the same directory, it works.

Basically:

```
cd /media
python
os.getcwd()
> '/media'
```

```
cd /media/N_drive
python
os.getcwd()
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
os.chdir('/media/N_drive')
os.getcwd()
> '/media/N_drive'
```

I [tried asking this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60207347/python-os-getcwd-randomly-fails-in-mounted-network-drive) over on Stack Overflow and the suggestion was that I am temporarily losing connection to the mounted drive. Although I can fix it with `os.chdir()` in my own script, any library I try to use (like pandas) invariably fails, because it usually tries to call `os.getcwd()`.

The strange thing is that this is not very repeatable or predictable - sometimes I can run `os.getcwd()` fine on the mounted drive, sometimes not, and I can't find a pattern.

Any ideas how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Did you ever work this out @howard-sherman